# Understanding a theorem of Marden's on the moduli of zeros of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

My question is concerning Theorem 3.2 in [this paper of Marden's](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183512041).  The gist of the theorem is stated below.

> **Theorem 3.2.**
>
> Every polynomial of the form
>
> $$ f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} (b_j - b_{j-1}) e^{i \theta_j} z^j $$
>
> where
>
> $$ b_{-1} = b_n = 0 < b_0 < b_1 < \cdots < b_{n-1} $$
>
> has all of its zeros in the disk $|z| \leq 1$.  Furthermore, every polynomial of the form
>
> $$ g(z) = b_0 + b_1 z + \cdots + b_{n-1} z^{n-1} $$
>
> has all of its zeros in the disk $|z| \leq 1$.

From the way the theorem is worded, it seems like the second part (about the zeros of $g(z)$) follows from the first part.  Is this the case?

The theorem is not proved in the paper.

Comment: Maybe this is a job for Schur-Cohn (or Routh-Hurwitz, after performing the customary Möbius transformation from a disk to a half-plane)?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. Do you know of a reference where I could learn about Schur-Cohn applied to polynomials with complex coefficients?

Comment: If memory serves, Marden's book ought to have it (I can't check at the moment, since I'm far away from my books). Otherwise, have a look at Henrici's *Applied and Computational Complex Analysis*; see also [this MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67049).

Comment: Where does $(1-z) g(z)$ have its roots?

Comment: @WimC If you copy your comment into the answer box, this question will leave the "unanswered" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does $(1-z)g(z)$ have its roots?